# graphql issue with route in golang

Tags: go, graphql, router, graphql-go

I used router in my code as:

```
router := chi.NewRouter()

router.Use(auth.Middleware())
srv := handler.NewDefaultServer(generated.NewExecutableSchema(generated.Config{Resolvers: &graph.Resolver{}}))

router.Handle("/", playground.Handler("GraphQL playground", "/query"))
router.Handle("/query", srv)
```

and got error like :

```
{
  "errors": {
    "message": "Unexpected token p in JSON at position 4",
    "stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 4"
  }
}
```

but when I Try using it with `http.Handle` it doesn't show error but the code inside `auth.middleware` doesn't run at all.

Comment: Are you following along the Learn GraphQL Golang path? What does your http.ListenAndServe line contain? Because I had a problem with , nil) instead of using router there.